# How to count the number of variables in a function - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments, decorator, counting

I want to be able to write a function that counts the number of arguments in a function, for example:

> > > counter("one", "two")
> > >
> > > 2
> > >
> > > counter("one", "two", "three")
> > >
> > > 3

etc,

I have this so far but I'm not sure it's right. Could someone help me out with this please? Thanks.

```
def counter(f):
    f.counter = 0
    def counting_f(*args):
        v = f(*args)
        f.counter += 1
        print("{0}: {1} times".format(f.__name__, f.counter))
        return v
    return counting_f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand what you want. Is it this :

```
def counter(*f):
  print len(f)

>>> counter("one", "two")
2

>>> counter("one", "two","three")
3
```

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago I came across to a really "powerful" d_word/magic word, termed as **code**.
Once accessed, it unlocks a wide range of proprieties by which you could find out information about your class/method/entity structure.

Hence, I'll permit myself to redesign your code in...

```
@staticmethod
def counting_f(arg1:str = "", arg2:str = "", arg3:str = ""):
    print(len(counting_f.__code__.co_argcount))
```

More elegant I would say.
So long as I didn't misunderstand your mark question...